# Disable scrolling of a PeerComponent (GoogleMap)

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to disable the X and Y scrolling of a GoogleMap inside a Codename One?
I'm referring to a map created using the cn1lib described here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-improved-native-google-maps.html

If the map is scrollable, then I cannot insert more than one map in a `Form`, otherwise the contentPane scrolling and map scrolling conflict. If the maps can be not scrollable, then I can insert more maps in the same `Form` without scrolling issues.

I know that I can use static maps (that are images), but I need that pinch-to-zoom and pin locators action listeners work.

Thank you

Comment: Google maps supports this using their cooperative gesture handling mode, but we don’t expose this property in the cn1lib currently.  It would need to be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Steves comment. There's no support for this in the peer component wrapping. We assume most peers are scrollable within as mixing scrolling and native peers with produce a bad experience. E.g. panning the map instead of scrolling or potential artifacts when the map and title area draw on top of each other when your page is scrolled down.

I would suggest you take a different route for this use case. Use a static image and when a user taps the map open a map in the bottom part of the screen as a dialog or as a separate form to provide the full map UX.

Comment: I agree that taking a different route for this use case could circumvent the issue, but it's not an option in my case. That's why I added this RFE: https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/issues/37